# Insert video info to database through the API

Tags: javascript, mysql, node.js, database, youtube-data-api

I have an own database of Youtube videos. What it contains so far is the id of these certain videos; the one which can be found in the video link as well.

I'm looking for a method that I can use to insert both the title and the description of them into the database by the use of the Youtube API and MySQL.

By the use of [the mysql npm](https://www.npmjs.com/package/mysql), I could connect to the database, but the async nature confuses me a bit.

**Here's my original (incomplete) code:**

```
var request = require('request');
var mysql      = require('mysql');

var connection = mysql.createConnection({
    host     : 'localhost',
    user     : 'root',
    password : (this is secret)
    database : 'video_db'
});

connection.query('SELECT id FROM videos', function(err, rows, fields) {
    if (err) throw err;

    for(i=0;i<rows.length-1;i++){

        var APIkey = (this is also secret)
        var videoid = rows[i].id;

        //gets data of a single video
        var API_URL = 'https://www.googleapis.com/youtube/v3/videos'
            + '?part=snippet'
            + '&id=' + videoid
            + '&key=' + APIkey;

        request(API_URL, function (error, response, body) {
          if (!error && response.statusCode == 200) {

                console.log(JSON.parse(body));
            } else {
                console.log(error);
            };
        });
    };
});
```

Questions:

1.) To make it work, another `connection.query` would be necessary within the `request`, but since that also works asynchronously, I'm quite unsure about the outcome. What is the proper way to write elements of that response into the database? Should I use another kind of apporach? Is it possible that writing the whole logic within `'SELECT id FROM videos'` was a bad idea?

2.) I tried the API links and they worked in the browser, but when the code itself runs, `request` throws and error, which consists of the following message:

```
{ [Error: connect ENOBUFS 216.58.214.202:443 - Local (undefined:undefined)]
  code: 'ENOBUFS',
  errno: 'ENOBUFS',
  syscall: 'connect',
  address: '216.58.214.202',
  port: 443 }
```

What's the source of this problem? (if it's viable to be another question on its own, I'm willing to remove from the original question, as this is less of the part of the original issue)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

1. Make Your query safe: add "ORDER BY id DESC LIMIT 10" to Your query. Otherwise it reads all records from table.
2. You're sending too many requests inside of for loop so You're wasting memory for requests (no buffers error) without waiting for one to finish.

Better to do it like this:

```
var request = require('request');
var mysql = require('mysql');
var async = require ('async');

var connection = mysql.createConnection({
    host     : 'localhost',
    user     : 'root',
    password : 'this is secret',
    database : 'video_db'
});

var APIkey = "SECRET KEY";

var apiUrls = [];
connection.query('SELECT id FROM videos ORDER id LIMIT 10', function(err, rows, ) {
    if (err) throw err;

    rows.forEach(function(row){
        var API_URL = 'https://www.googleapis.com/youtube/v3/videos'
            + '?part=snippet'
            + '&id=' + row.id
            + '&key=' + APIkey;
        apiUrls.push(API_URL);
    };
});

async.eachSeries(apiUrls, function(apiUrl, next){

    request(apiUrl, function (error, response, body) {
        if(error || response.statusCode != 200) {
            console.error(response.statusCode, error);
            return next();
        }

        console.log(JSON.parse(body));
        next();
    });
});
```

OR if You insist to loop all of records:

```
var request = require('request');
var mysql = require('mysql');
var async = require ('async');

var connection = mysql.createConnection({
    host     : 'localhost',
    user     : 'root',
    password : 'this is secret',
    database : 'video_db'
});

var APIkey = "SECRET KEY";

connection.query('SELECT id FROM videos', function(err, rows) {
    if (err) throw err;

    async.eachSeries(rows, function(row, next){
        //gets data of a single video
        var apiUrl = 'https://www.googleapis.com/youtube/v3/videos'
            + '?part=snippet'
            + '&id=' + row.id
            + '&key=' + APIkey;

        request(apiUrl, function (error, response, body) {
            if(error || response.statusCode != 200) {
                console.error(response.statusCode, error);
                return next();
            }

            console.log(JSON.parse(body));
            next();
        });
    };
});
```